# FireBase authentication benefits

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

This question might sound silly to some, my scenario was that i had to implement facebook login in my mobile app.

**I added to my project:**

1. Facebook SDK
2. Firebase authentication SDK
3. Implement both Facebook login and Firebase authentication mechanism for facebook.

Couldn't i just implement facebook SDK and implement the login?

I understand the benefit of receiving statistics about users and logins from different social networks in one place.

Are there more benefits i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely to use Firebase Authentication if you

- Use other Firebase products, which integrate with it. For example [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) integrates with Firebase Authentication to provide a [server-side security model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview), while allowing direct database access from the client.
- Use multiple providers, and want to link them together. [Firebase Authentication allows accounts to be linked](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking), so that a user ends up with one profile, no matter if they sign in with Facebook today, and with Google tomorrow.

Comment: This is essentially the answer. Firebase Auth allows for easy integration with other Firebase services as well as multiple auth providers handled identically within the Firebase ecosystem.