# what is the advantage of using fire base authentication for Facebook login for android

Tags: android, google-signin, fbconnect

**I have Integrated FB and Google login sdk's in my app, I saw that we can authenticate user by using Fire-base for both Google and FB.**

What is the advantage of using Firebase Auth for FB and gmail?

Comment: refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52064669/6630837)